# Liquibase-CDI throwing WELD exception after running successfully on Payara Micro

Tags: liquibase, weld

I am trying to implement liquibase in my JEE8 application using `liquibase-cdi`.
Liquibase starts up, **runs all migrations successfully**, but then throws the following exception, which **causes the deploy to fail**.

**Payara 5.182.RC5** Exception:

```
16:05:10.263 [main] DEBUG liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor - Release Database Lock
16:05:10.265 [main] DEBUG liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor - UPDATE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1
16:05:10.266 [main] INFO liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService - Successfully released change log lock
2018-06-12T16:05:10.286+0200] [] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1528812310286] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase.onStartup() on liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase@5f0b2fe1 -- WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase.onStartup() on liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase@5f0b2fe1
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:499)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.processApplicationLoaded(WeldDeployer.java:511)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:133)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.deployAll(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1553)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.bootStrap(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1036)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.main(PayaraMicroImpl.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:70)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.PayaraMicroLauncher.main(PayaraMicroLauncher.java:79)
    at fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro.main(PayaraMicro.java:397)
]]

[2018-06-12T16:05:10.287+0200] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1528812310287] [levelValue: 1000] Exception while loading the app

[2018-06-12T16:05:10.293+0200] [] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00192] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1528812310293] [levelValue: 1000] Undeployment failed for context
```

My CDI class:

```
@Dependent
public class LiquibaseCdiIntegration {

    @Resource
    private DataSource myDataSource;

    @Produces
    @LiquibaseType
    public CDILiquibaseConfig createConfig() {
        CDILiquibaseConfig config = new CDILiquibaseConfig();
        config.setChangeLog("liquibase/changelog.xml");
        return config;
    }

    @Produces
    @LiquibaseType
    public DataSource createDataSource() throws SQLException {
        return myDataSource;
    }

    @Produces
    @LiquibaseType
    public ResourceAccessor create() {
        return new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(getClass().getClassLoader());
    }
}
```

From my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Since my `changelog.xml` runs successfully, I won't paste it here.

EDIT: (Might be relevant)

When trying to deploy to **Payara Micro 5.181** the following error happens:

```
[2018-06-12T16:20:16.355+0200] [] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Validator] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1528813216355] [levelValue: 900] WELD-001473: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean implementation liquibase.integration.cdi.CDIBootstrap$1@1798c749 declared a normal scope but does not implement javax.enterprise.inject.spi.PassivationCapable. It won't be possible to inject this bean into a bean with a passivating scope (@SessionScoped, @ConversationScoped). This can be fixed by assigning the Bean implementation a unique id by implementing the PassivationCapable interface.

No valid EE environment for injection of liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase
No valid EE environment for injection of de.ccsys.sns.monitoring.config.LiquibaseCdiIntegration
No valid EE environment for injection of de.ccsys.sns.monitoring.config.LiquibaseCdiIntegration
No valid EE environment for injection of de.ccsys.sns.monitoring.config.LiquibaseCdiIntegration
16:20:16.615 [main] INFO liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase - Booting Liquibase 3.6.1
[2018-06-12T16:20:16.736+0200] [] [WARNING] [NCLS-CORE-00069] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1528813216736] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Exception while dispatching an event
org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationException
    at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.postInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.processApplicationLoaded(WeldDeployer.java:522)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:426)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:134)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.deployAll(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1531)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.bootStrap(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1019)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.main(PayaraMicroImpl.java:201)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:70)
    at fish.payara.micro.boot.PayaraMicroLauncher.main(PayaraMicroLauncher.java:79)
    at fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro.main(PayaraMicro.java:383)
]]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I created a new project from zero and there it works... https://github.com/gmussi/liquibase-payara-micro-example

Answer (score 1):

I also had to deal with this issue. Similar configuration `Java EE8`, `Payara 5.183`, and using `Liquibase 3.6.1`.

The issue is related to how `WELD (CDI)` is wrapping the exception thrown by Liquibase during the execution of the database scripts. The explicit message for the error cause is not been printed in the logs, but it is usually related to an error on the instructions of the liquibase changeset.

In my case, I was adding a primary key but I had forgotten to put the constraint name. Once I fixed that, it started working.
If any one is getting the same error, please start by checking the instructions in the changeset.

*The above answer is based on [Liquibase-CDI fails to deploy after successful run](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2834), reported by owner of this question (who already mentioned his problem is fixed). But it's worthy to detail the cause and possible aproaches to fix it, for other people with the same problem.*