# Payara DataSource not being injected

Tags: liquibase, payara, java-ee-8

I'm using Payara 5.184 and Java 1.8.241 on Linux (Ubuntu 19.10). I'm also using Liquibase as my database schema change management. A field named **myDataSource** is being injected as follows:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:global/ds")
private DataSource myDataSource;
```

When the method **createDataSource()** from Liquibase is invoked I noticed that the variable **myDataSource** is null, what makes me understand that the resource is not being properly injected. This error seems to happen only on Linux, as my other colleagues that run Windows did not have any problems so far. We're using exactly the same versions of Payara/Java. Is there any specific step that needs to be done on Linux? Here it is the stacktrace found on Payara logs.

```
 Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase.onStartup() on liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase@911a89a
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:122)
    at liquibase.integration.cdi.CDIBootstrap$1.create(CDIBootstrap.java:95)
    at liquibase.integration.cdi.CDIBootstrap$1.create(CDIBootstrap.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:131)
    at liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
    at liquibase.integration.cdi.CDIBootstrap.afterDeploymentValidation(CDIBootstrap.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
    at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:499)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.processApplicationLoaded(WeldDeployer.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:428)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:83)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase.performUpdate(CDILiquibase.java:126)
    at liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase.onStartup(CDILiquibase.java:116)
    ... 79 more
```

EDIT: Added stacktrace

EDIT 2: **Problem solved!** It ended up being something not related with Liquibase at all. The queue size of the PayaraExecutorService was too small, which leads me to think that some tasks submissions were rejected. Apparently this is a known issue of **Payara 5.184**, and a related issue had already been opened on Github (https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/3495). Once I increased the size of the queue to a large number everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `lookup` to inject the resource.

Compare this bug report: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4413

Comment: I've already tried that before and it didn't work for me. I'm now using method based injection to check if the DataSource is being set, but the breakpoint inside the setter method is not hit, so I presume that the injection is not working for some reason.

Comment: So it is the same stack trace but a different problem. Strange indeed. If you already tried that you should tell that in the description to prevent people from wasting their time.

Comment: The issue that you posted refers to Payara 5.194, but I'm using Payara 5.184, so the problem might not be related. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok sorry, misread that. I guess you also checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819480/liquibase-cdi-throwing-weld-exception-after-running-successfully-on-payara-micro It suggests that errors in the changeset itself also could produce these kind of errors.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is now solved and it has nothing to do with Liquibase at all. Apparently the default queue size of PayaraExecutorService was too small. Once I increased it to a large number everything started working perfectly. Check my EDIT 2 for more details.

Comment: I remember that bug. We were also affected by it since it affected pretty much everything. ;) With the specific error message from the rejected executions it would have been easy to help you.